# Access variables in methods that are in a class, outside of that class

Tags: ruby, class, variables, object

I have the following code that creates a viking game character and gives them random stats such as health, age and strength.

```
class Viking
    def initialize(name, health, age, strength)
        @name = name
        @health = health
        @age = age
        @strength = strength
    end
    def self.create_warrior(name)
        age = rand * 20 + 15
        health = [age * 5, 120].min
        strength = [age/2, 10].min
        Viking.new(name, health, age, strength)
    end
end

brad = Viking.create_warrior("Brad")

puts "New Warrior Created!"
```

The create_warrior function returns all those values, but how do I access them so I could see the stats.

For example this doesn't work but I would like to see the age or health of the new Viking brad (i.e `brad.age` even though that wouldn't work because it's not a method).

So how do I access those variables (without making them global).

Comment: Are you sure you want to put the ruby-on-rails tag? If you want to save things in database you should use Active Record instead.

Comment: You already have the solution: "`brad.age` even though that wouldn't work because it's not a method" – So make it one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `attr_accessor :name, :health, :age, :strength` if you would like the variables to be both readable and writable or `attr_reader :name, :health, :age, :strength` if you would like them to be read only.

After this you can access with `brad.varname` e.g. `brad.name` etc...

[[Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)]

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr_reader :age`, so you can simply use `brad.age`, same goes for the other variables

Answer (score 1):

If you **really don't want them global**, try `instance_variable_get` method http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get

```
puts brad.instance_variable_get(:@age)
```

Comment: there are no public, nor global instance variables in Ruby

Comment: i think if you have an accessor method for an instance variable, that variable becomes 'public'

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attr_reader` method, it creates a attribute method to point to the variable in the `initialize` method which is private. Its **read-only**

You can use `attr_writer` to **write only**

And `attr_accessor` to  both **read and write**

```
class Viking

  attr_reader    :age, :name, :health, :strength

        def initialize(name, health, age, strength)
            @name = name
            @health = health
            @age = age
            @strength = strength
        end
        def self.create_warrior(name)
            age = rand * 20 + 15
            health = [age * 5, 120].min
            strength = [age/2, 10].min
            Viking.new(name, health, age, strength)
        end
    end

    brad = Viking.create_warrior("Brad")

    puts "New Warrior Created!"
```